On the norm of adjoint operator $T^\times$: Theorem 4.5.2 Kreyszig.
We start with the
Definition. Let $T\colon X \to Y$ be a bounded linear operator, where $X$ and $Y$ are normed spaces. Then the adjoint operator $T^\times Y^* \to X^*$ of $T$ is defined by
$$f(x)=(T^\times g)(x)=g(Tx)\quad (g\in Y^*),$$
where $X^*$ and $Y^*$ are
the dual spaces of $X$ and $Y$, respectively.
Theorem. The adjoint operator $T^\times$ defined above is linear and bounded, and $$\lVert T^\times \rVert =\lVert T \rVert.$$
It is simple to prove that the operator $T^\times$ is linear and bounded with $$\lVert T^\times \rVert \le \lVert T \rVert. $$
We must prove that $\lVert T^\times \rVert \ge \lVert T \rVert$. We use the following
Theorem (Bounded linear funtionals) Let $X$ be a normed space and let $x_0\ne 0$ be any element of $X$. then there exists a bounded linear functional $\tilde{f}$ on $X$ such that $$\lVert \tilde{f} \rVert =1, \qquad \tilde{f}(x_0)=\lVert x_0 \rVert.$$
At first I write exactly what is written in the text.
The Theorem(Bounded linear functionals) implies that for every nonzero $x_0\in X$ there is a $g_0\in Y^*$ such that $$\lVert g_0 \rVert = 1\qquad g_0(Tx_0)=\lVert Tx_0 \rVert.$$
Here, $g_0(Tx_0)=(T^\times g_0)(x_0)$ by the definition of the adjoint operator $T^\times$. Writing $f_0=T^\times g_0$, we thus obtain
\begin{align}
\lVert Tx_0 \rVert = g_0(Tx_0)=&f_0(x_0)\\
\le & \lVert f_0 \rVert \lVert x_0 \rVert \\
= & \lVert T^\times g_0 \rVert \lvert x_0 \rVert \\
\le & \lVert T^\times \rVert \lVert g_0 \rVert \lVert x_0 \rVert 
\end{align}
Since $\lVert g_0 \rVert = 1$, we thus have for every $x_0\in X$ $$\lVert Tx_0 \rVert \le \lVert T^\times \rVert \lVert x_0 \rVert.$$
Written this way it does not seem formally correct to me in accordance with the theorem(bounded linear functionals). Here is how I rewrote.
We suppose that $T\ne 0$ and let $x_0\in X$ such that $Tx_0\ne 0$, then there is a $g_0\in Y^*$ such that $$\lVert g_0 \rVert = 1\qquad g_0(Tx_0)=\lVert Tx_0 \rVert.$$
Here, $g_0(Tx_0)=(T^\times g_0)(x_0)$ by the definition of the adjoint operator $T^\times$. Writing $f_0=T^\times g_0$, we thus obtain
\begin{align}
\lVert Tx_0 \rVert = g_0(Tx_0)=&f_0(x_0)\\
\le & \lVert f_0 \rVert \lVert x_0 \rVert \\
= & \lVert T^\times g_0 \rVert \lvert x_0 \rVert \\
\le & \lVert T^\times \rVert \lVert g_0 \rVert \lVert x_0 \rVert 
\end{align}
Since $\lVert g_0 \rVert = 1$, we thus have for every $x_0\in X$ with $Tx_0\ne 0$ $$\lVert Tx_0 \rVert \le \lVert T^\times \rVert \lVert x_0 \rVert.\tag1$$
Now we observe that $(1)$ hold also when $Tx_0=0$ then we have that or every $x_0\in X$ $$\lVert Tx_0 \rVert \le \lVert T^\times \rVert \lVert x_0 \rVert.$$

Is this rewrite clearer? Or is there something in what Kreyszig writes that I don't understand?


I mean, this seems just a formality. If I’m the one judging this proof, I would be perfectly happy with the first version. (As a purely technical point, the first version is formally wrong since it can be the case that $Y$ is the zero space but $X$ is not, but I don’t think anyone would really care about zero spaces anyway.)

@DavidGaoThanks for your interest. I'm not so sure about your explanation. Suppose $Y$ is not the trivial space, but who guarantees that if we choose $x_0\ne 0$ in $X$, then $Tx_0\ne 0$?

We cannot. But again, that’s just a formality. After all, the theorem you cited is obviously true if $x_0 = 0$, as long as the space is not trivial. There’s no need to dogmatically adhere to the form of the theorem as written. (I would assume the theorem specifically assumes $x_0 \neq 0$ for the sole reason to exclude the trivial space case.)

@DavidGaoOk, thanks!
